# How to sort the list order using Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

Below is the order of the Data that I get in the list object from other service.

[image: Data in List]

> How can I sort the order of above list in the below order?

Level 0 Class
Level 0 S-Class
Level 1 Class
Level 1 S-Class
Level 2 Class
Level 2 S-Class
Level 0 Lesson
Level 0 S-Lesson
Level 1 Lesson
Level 1 S-Lesson
Level 2 Lesson
Level 2 S-Lesson

So far I have tried as below, but only getting the right order for ProgramId "E".

```
    myList.OrderByDescending(x => x.ProgramId== "E")
          .ThenBy(x => x.Level)
          .ThenBy(x => x.Special = True)
          .ThenBy(x => x.Special = False)
          .ThenByDescending(x => x.ProgramId== "B")
          .ThenBy(x => x.Level)
          .ThenBy(x => x.Special = True)
          .ThenBy(x => x.Special = False);
```

Below is the sorting logic that I am trying to apply:

- It should be sorted based on ProgramId first followed by Level and Followed by Special = false, followed by Special = true.
- Within ProgramId, sorting order should be "E" followed by "B".
- Within Level, sorting order should be Level 0 followed by Level 1 followed by Level 2

Any help suggestion on this would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you actually know how it's sorted?  It doesn't look like it's anything like you've specified.  It looks like `ProgramDescription` then `Level`.

Comment: Thanks for asking more details @CharlesMager, I have described the sort logic in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will produce the order you have requested:

```
myList = myList.OrderByDescending(x => x.ProgramId)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Level)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Special);
```

I have no idea why you think this doesn't work, but I have now tested it and it works exactly to your specification.

[Here is a working example](https://ideone.com/GyoOW9)

Comment: Yes @musefan, can not go by the description!

Comment: @seUser: So use my first one, it will sort the booleans correctly. `ThenBy` will sort false first which is what you want, do not use descending

Comment: Yes but it only works for programid 'E' only and not for the 'B'

Comment: @seUser: My answer works exactly as you have asked, I have now added a link to prove that it works exactly as you have asked. I don't understand why you think it doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks @musefan: I am excepting this answer, because it is correct based on my sample. I did the actual implementation based on below two lines.

`  
  var groups = myList.OrderBy(x => x.Level).GroupBy(x => x.ProgramID);

   var sortedMyList = groups.SelectMany(group => group).ToList();

Answer (score 3):

try this?

```
 myList.OrderByDescending(x => x.ProgramId)
              .ThenBy(x => x.Level)
              .ThenByDescending(x => x.Special)
```

Comment: Pretty sure booleans order `false, true`, not the other way around. I wonder who upvoted this...

Comment: Thanks David & musefan, actually I want to show the not special first so David suggestion should work, however I have more than two ProgramId than what I showed in the sample data. So with above sort logic I am only getting the right order for ProgramId "E" after that I get order by level only, not sure why, as shown below:
Level 0 Class, 
Level 0 S-Class, 
Level 1 Class, 
Level 1 S-Class, 
Level 2 Class, 
Level 2 S-Class, 
Level 0 Lesson, 
Level 1 Lesson, 
Level 2 Lesson, 
Level 1 S-Lesson, 
Level 0 S-Lesson, 
Level 2 S-Lesson

Comment: @seUser: If you have more program ids then edit your questions and include them all, it is very important to the solution

Comment: @musefan: I have added the logic description to be more clear on what sorting logic I am trying to implement, hope that helps!

Comment: I have tested this now, and this will only work if `Special` is a string. If `Special` is a boolean like the question implies then you will get the wrong order

Comment: @musefan At which point, just reverse the direction on the Special field.  It's really not that hard to figure out.

Comment: @Immersive: Well the OP certainly seems to be having trouble with it

Comment: I read OP's question as being about sort priority, not direction.  Certainly, a particular direction is required to achieve the specified result, but surely we can assume that OP is capable of recognising when ASC should be DESC, or vice versa.

I do note you had an identical answer, with the inverted `special` direction.

Answer (score -1):

```
.OrderBy(x => x.Level).ThenBy(x => x.ProgramDescription)
```

Comment: You will get: `0 class, 0 lesson, 0 s-class, 0 s-lesson, ...`